# Are there numbers with the property that the sum of their squares equals the square of their sum?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Are there numbers a and b with the property that

$a^2 + b^2= (a+b)^2$

Note that the answer is yes. For instance, **$a=0 , b= \mathbb{R}$** would work. Can you think of other numbers that would also work?

I have found that it will also work when $a=0 , b=0$

Can you think of others ?

Comment: If you open the parentheses and evaluate, you get the condition $ab=0$. End of story.

Comment: I did it sir, and that is why I assumed that either a or b equals 0. But do you think that there is any possible answer rather that what stated above ? I am learning math from beginning so I would appreciate more elaboration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you allow more than two numbers, there are more interesting answers, e.g., $(1+2+(-2/3))^2=1^2+2^2+(-2/3)^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson your answer does not hold with conditions. However, I am interested to know how did you got those combination ?

Comment: I solved $(1+2+x)^2=1^2+2^2+x^2$ for $x$. Pick your favorite $a,b$, and you can solve $(a+b+x)^2=a^2+b^2+x^2$ for $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson great job thank you very much. That was informative.

Comment: OK. Are you ready to accept Aaron Daniel's answer, or do you need something more?

Comment: Actually his answer is same as mine. I was asking to verify and I got the answer and I got more than that (your answer)

Comment: I am new here I just got that you must click on right symbol to accept the answer. But why his answer only why not your ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the comments you can reduce the property in the following way
$$ a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 \Leftrightarrow 0 = 2 a b$$
which just reduces to $a b = 0$. Therefore the solutions you found are all there are because for a product to be zero at least one of the factors has to be zero.